# Circle cut outs (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to recreate this image
[image]

I have no idea how to make ideal cutouts with rounded edges and place them closer to the center. 
To accomplish this I tried making an arch form and using pathfinder cut out the form, but I can bet that there is an easier and much faster way to recreate this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create two circles
Add a stroke to them with *rounded end caps*
Use the **Scissors Tool** to cut the circles into pieces
Delete the pieces you do not want

[image]

Comment: Shoot, you beat me to it. Almost exactly the same answer!

Comment: Impressive. You are very fast (flash).

Answer (score 5):

You could start with a circle, add extra anchor points using the Add Anchor Point tool, then simply delete the segments you don't want by selecting them with the Direct Selection tool, and deleting.

Finish by adding Round Caps to the Stroke, in the Stroke dialog.

[image]